# Visual Studio: Build Setup Project that does not require .Net Framework

Tags: winforms, setup-project

Lately I have made a windows forms Project in VS 2010. Then I built it in VS 2005 Setup Project. Before installation my software requires .Net Framework to be installed. Most of my users don't want this, instead they just want to download the software and install, just like they download Skype, IM, etc.

I can add Framework in installation folder, but then it's size would be too large and that's inconvenient for users again.

Is there any way to build my Project, that will NOT require .Net Framework installation?